# How to Display and Hide reply form only when a reply button is clicked

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to add reply comments to my comment system in a Laravel 8 project. I have written a script to show the reply form when the reply button is clicked but the form is always in displayed by default. However, when the reply button is clicked, the form hides and shows on the second click. I seem not to get what I am not getting right. Please, I need your assistant in this regard. This is my code:

```
//The form    
<div class="card-body">
     @if ($PostDetails->comment)
         @foreach($PostDetails->comment as $comment)
             <blockquote class="blockquote">
             <p class="mb-0">{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
             <footer class="blockquote-footer">{{ $comment->user->name }}</footer>
             </blockquote>
             {{-- Reply Comment Section --}}
             <button id="reply-button" onclick="showReplyForm('{{$comment->id}}', '{{ $comment->user->name }}')" class="border-0 bg-transparent">Reply</button>
             <div class="row flex-row d-flex">
                  <form action="" method="post">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <textarea id="reply-form-{{$comment->id}}" cols="80" rows="2" class="form-control mb-10" name="replyMessage"></textarea>
                       </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
              <hr>
         @endforeach
       @endif
</div>

//The script is:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showReplyForm(commentId){
        var x = document.getElementById(`reply-form-${commentId}`);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to make it hidden to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `id` attribute for your buttons to `class="reply-button"` and add the `style="display:none"` to your `textareas`. Then you can simplify your JavaScript part to

```
document.querySelectorAll(".reply-button").forEach(btn=>btn.onclick=ev=>{      
  const x=ev.target.nextElementSibling.querySelector("textarea");
  x.style.display = x.style.display ==="none"?"":"none";
});
```

Then there is no need to assign `id`s to the individual textareas anymore.

Comment: Works perfectly even when submit button is included. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `style="display:none;"` to make it hidden at start.

```
<div class="card-body">
     @if ($PostDetails->comment)
         @foreach($PostDetails->comment as $comment)
             <blockquote class="blockquote">
             <p class="mb-0">{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
             <footer class="blockquote-footer">{{ $comment->user->name }}</footer>
             </blockquote>
             {{-- Reply Comment Section --}}
             <button id="reply-button" onclick="showReplyForm('{{$comment->id}}', '{{ $comment->user->name }}')" class="border-0 bg-transparent">Reply</button>
             
             <div class="row flex-row d-flex" style="display:none">
                  <form action="" method="post">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <textarea id="reply-form-{{$comment->id}}" cols="80" rows="2" class="form-control mb-10" name="replyMessage"></textarea>
                       </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
              <hr>
         @endforeach
       @endif
</div>

//The script is:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showReplyForm(commentId){
        var x = document.getElementById(`reply-form-${commentId}`);

        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Adding style="display: none" to the div does not work perfectly but when added to the textarea works only that when a button is included it does not. Have tried the suggestion by Carsten Massmann and it works perfectly. Thanks anyways.